# How to access class methods from another file

Tags: ruby, selenium

I have a main file, and want to pull some code out of it and move it to another, however it doesn't work with instances. For example:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "./out.rb"
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com"

hello
save
```

out.rb is:

```
def save
  driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
end

def hello
  puts "hello"
end

hello
in `<main>': undefined local variable or method `save' for main:Object(NameError)
```

How do I access the class methods from another file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods are accessible in the first file. In essence, doing the require is the same as writing it all in the same file.

By doing just that, you can see part of your problem:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"

def save
  driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
end

def hello
  puts "hello"
end

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com"

hello
save
```

The variable `driver` is not available inside of the method `save`.

One way around this is to let `save` take the driver as an argument:

```
def save(driver)
  driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
end

# Call the method like this
save(driver)
```

Some points:

- Writing code in the global scope like this is not advisable. Try wrapping what you want to do in a class.
- The methods you've defined aren't really class methods. As @JörgWMittag pointed out: `they become private instance methods of Object`

Comment: Thanks. May you also post a good tutorial for understanding classes in a deep way.

Comment: "Writing methods in the global scope defines them on an Object called main." – No, they become `private` instance methods of `Object`, not singleton methods of `main` (except in IRb, where they become `public` instance methods of `Object`).

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, @JörgWMittag, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question appeared to be -- as far as I can tell -- more of a Ruby question and not entirely dependent on Selenium, there is another approach you could take.

That's to use: `require_relative './out'`

If the out.rb file is located in a different folder you will need to specify the path, but I have written several programs where I only did something like this `require_relative 'out'`. I haven't quite figured out why it does or doesn't demand the ./ prefix, so you're better off trying it with that first.

Give this a try:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require_relative "./out"

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "http://www.google.com"

hello
save
```